# javascript inheritance with 'that'

Tags: javascript, this, multiple-inheritance

Can anyone please help me. I am trying to get along with multiple inheritance. But my code isn't working, because my object obja don't know sayhello().

It is importent that the line

> var that = new InputModule();

is included. But I have no idea how to fix it.

```
 var InputModule = function(title, type){


     var that = this;

     that.title = title;
     that.type = type;
     that.return = null;

     that.sayHello = function(){
         console.log("Hello! I'm " + that.title + " and I'm an " + that.type + "Module!");
     }

}

var IntModule = function(){

    var that = new InputModule("newti", "int");

}

var obja = new IntModule();
obja.sayHello();
```

EDIT:

What I want is that IntModul is an InputModul which can use the function sayhello();.
My Coworker said I sholudn't use prototype and sould use the line "var that = new InputModule".
Than I create a new Modul which is an IntModul and sould use also sayhello() because it is an InputModul. But there are other Moduls like LetterModul that should also inherit from InputModul.
I hope that makes sense. I'm frustrated...

Comment: there isn't a reason in this code that you need to assign that = this.

Comment: It would help if you would explain what you *expect* your code to do. You say that line is "important": why?  It doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Multiple inheritance? Your example does not even show single inheritance. Also `return` is a keyword.

Comment: This is single-inheritance. Or would be, except you're not inheriting anything.

Comment: This is composition, not inheritance.

Comment: I just edit it @Pointy

Comment: I think your coworker is directing you poorly.  Because you have no functions defined on the prototype, you can skip much of the usual prototype juggling used in various inheritance schemes.  But the line suggested by the coworker makes no sense.  See my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is a simple inheritance hierarchy.  If you're trying to do true multiple inheritance, you are out of luck, as Javascript's prototypal inheritance model only allows an object to have one prototype object. You would need to use a mixin technique to get something close.

You could probably get the behavior you want with something like this:

```
var IntModule = function() {
  InputModule.call(this, "newte", "int");   
}
```

If you are intent on using inheritance in JS, though, you might look at [ES2015 class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), which -- while not changing the under-the-covers behavior -- simplifies the syntax quite a bit.

In your code, there is no reason for `that` in `InputModule`, although it does no harm.  But in `IntModule` you use it to create a new object, and not to modify the object you're trying to create.  And then you do nothing with the object `that`.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interessted here is how I solved it:
It is not direct inheritance. But works the same way and is (for me)
more clearly than using prototyp.
You build your Instances and extend it with JQuery at the end.

`$.extend(true,this,that);`

You just extend it with the other Instances.

Maybe I described my problem not correctly. But this is excatly what I was looking for.